# Scaling database in a microservice architecture

Tags: database, microservices, high-availability

Lets say we have 5 microservices (μS) and each microservice requires one database with a few tables. Each of these services needs to be able to scale including the database queries. To do that we have a few options that I know of:

**1. 1-μS; 1 instance; 1 DB instance**

Don't scale horizontally, just vertically.

**2. 1-μS; N instances; 1 DB instance**

Every instance of a service gets to read and write to the same database. Simple way to scale if the service processing is the bottleneck.

**3. 1-μS; N instances; HA DB cluster**

Every instance of a service gets to read and write to the same HA database. Good way to scale if the database read/write is also a bottleneck. Greater operation cost.

**4. N-μS; N instances; HA DB cluster**

Every instance of every service gets to read and write to the same HA database cluster. Each service uses its own database in the HA DB cluster.

**5. Other**

Are there other ways to scale a database alongside the service that requires it?

---

With each solution there are trade-offs, whether it be read or write performance, operation cost etc., but what would be recommended solution for scaling database:

- with service and database being equal in a way that scaling a service required scaling the database ?
- with service requiring more processing time meaning that the service needs to scale and not the database ?
- with database requiring more processing time than the service ?

My opinion is that if a servise is high on writes then 3 or 4 is a solution and for the rest 4 is a solution.

Comment: Too broad and opinion base question.